# Sketching a complicated function

Tags: calculus, functions

How does one sketch $t^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})$ without using graphing devices? I know that we could use the method of sketching separate points and then connecting them, but I don't think that this method is appropriate in this case.

Also, why is the envelope of the function defined by $t^2$?

Comment: Sine oscillates between $1$ and $-1$; that's why the envelope is what it is.  And as $t$ goes down to $0$ then $\pi/t$ goes up to $\infty$, so the sine oscillates infinitely many times between any value of $t$ and $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

First think of $\sin(\pi/t)$.  This will be zero when $t=1,\frac12,\frac13$ etc.  So we have a wave which still has (vertical) range from $-1$ to $1$, but "squished up" horizontally so that the zeros get closer and closer together as we approach the origin.  Now multiply by $t^2$.  This doesn't affect the zeros, but the wave (if you still call it a wave) has "amplitude" which is not constant but gets (parabolically) larger and larger as $t\to\infty$.  It would probably be good also to draw the two parabolas $y=\pm t^2$ as bounding curves for your graph.  Finally, I have implicitly assumed that $t$ is positive, but since the function is odd, its graph for negative $t$ is found by rotating the graph we already have about the origin.

Comment: Perfect and very clear, thank you!